# Making two new directory in google colab and join them

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using google colab python 3 and I want to use this code it is running in jupyter notebook but don't running in google colab

i try !mkdir but still i cant join them

```
# Create a new directory
base_dir = 'base_dir'
os.mkdir(base_dir)
# create a path to 'base_dir' to which we will join the names of the new folder
# train_dir
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train_dir')
os.mkdir(train_dir)
```

i want to join base_dir and train_dir

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this would works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

#Create a new directory (a folder) in your Drive
tf.gfile.MkDir(base_dir)

#Combine the 2 strings
string = ('base_dir', 'train_dir')
s = ''
train_dir = s.join(string)

#Create the second directory
tf.gfile.MkDir(train_dir)
```